# :not() apply for all html tags in specific class

Tags: css, less

I have structure like
...

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="locket-wrapper">
```

...
there is many many code before and after. What i wanna do is not apply style for locket-wrapper and for all locket-wrapper elements. I am using less and wanna do something like this:

....

```
> div:not(.footer .locket-wrapper)
```

...

Is any possibility how to do it? I cannot use in my case div:not only for locket-wrapper class...